# jQuery and REST API to list all subsites and users in those subsites with full control

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, jquery-ajax

I'm looking to display on a web part in SharePoint online a list of all sub-sites and all users with full control to that particular site i.e.

Team Site                       Site Owners
https://ab/sharepoint.com       joe bloggs, missy bloggs
https://ac/sharepoint.com       amanda bloggs, tim jow, ted harold
https://ad/sharepoint.com       ralph noggin, lisa nerald

This list needs to be viewable by all users in the business no matter what permission level they have as it will be on a team site landing page where users can see what teams already exist and who to contact if they need access or want to ask a question of the site owner.
Is this possible what JQUERY and Rest Api?
Thanks,
Clare

Answer (score 0):

You can use following URL to get subsites from parent web.

```
http://company.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs
```

As for coding the web-part to how to display is, you can review this [example](http://sharepoint247.com/wss3/subsites-webpart-source-code/) and [description](http://sharepoint247.com/sharepoint2010/new-version-of-the-subsites-webpart-available-as-a-free-download/).

As for how to set up the view, Since you've mentioned you want to let everyone on site to see your web-part, you can just create with public view. [Reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother-mso_o365b/how-do-i-modify-the-view-of-the-document-library/0b02f4ba-0c26-4116-b460-08d45e0352b8)